# Opencv Unhandled Exception whe use cvCretateImage()

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013

I have the code below. Is a open realtime edge detection, but i had an error on line: `pProcessedFrame = cvCreateImage(cvSize(pFrame->width, pFrame->height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);`

"Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF6CAF1284C in opencv2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000000000000002C."

Anybody can resolve this insue?

My configuration is Visual Studio 2013 and Opencv 2.4.10

```
 #include <iostream>
#include "opencv/cv.h"
#include "opencv/highgui.h"
using namespace std;

// Define the IplImage pointers we're going to use as globals
IplImage* pFrame;
IplImage* pProcessedFrame;
IplImage* tempFrame;

// Slider for the low threshold value of our edge detection
int maxLowThreshold = 1024;
int lowSliderPosition = 150;

// Slider for the high threshold value of our edge detection
int maxHighThreshold = 1024;
int highSliderPosition = 250;

// Function to find the edges of a given IplImage object
IplImage* findEdges(IplImage* sourceFrame, double thelowThreshold, double theHighThreshold, double theAperture)
{
    // Convert source frame to greyscale version (tempFrame has already been initialised to use greyscale colour settings)
    cvCvtColor(sourceFrame, tempFrame, CV_RGB2GRAY);

    // Perform canny edge finding on tempframe, and push the result back into itself!
    cvCanny(tempFrame, tempFrame, thelowThreshold, theHighThreshold, theAperture);

    // Pass back our now processed frame!
    return tempFrame;
}

// Callback function to adjust the low threshold on slider movement
void onLowThresholdSlide(int theSliderValue)
{
    lowSliderPosition = theSliderValue;
}

// Callback function to adjust the high threshold on slider movement
void onHighThresholdSlide(int theSliderValue)
{
    highSliderPosition = theSliderValue;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Create two windows
    cvNamedWindow("WebCam", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cvNamedWindow("Processed WebCam", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    // Create the low threshold slider
    // Format: Slider name, window name, reference to variable for slider, max value of slider, callback function
    cvCreateTrackbar("Low Threshold", "Processed WebCam", &lowSliderPosition, maxLowThreshold, onLowThresholdSlide);

    // Create the high threshold slider
    cvCreateTrackbar("High Threshold", "Processed WebCam", &highSliderPosition, maxHighThreshold, onHighThresholdSlide);

    // Create CvCapture object to grab data from the webcam
    CvCapture* pCapture;

    // Start capturing data from the webcam
    pCapture = cvCaptureFromCAM(CV_CAP_V4L2);

    // Display image properties
    cout << "Width of frame: " << cvGetCaptureProperty(pCapture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH) << endl;      // Width of the frames in the video stream
    cout << "Height of frame: " << cvGetCaptureProperty(pCapture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT) << endl;    // Height of the frames in the video stream
    cout << "Image brightness: " << cvGetCaptureProperty(pCapture, CV_CAP_PROP_BRIGHTNESS) << endl;     // Brightness of the image (only for cameras)
    cout << "Image contrast: " << cvGetCaptureProperty(pCapture, CV_CAP_PROP_CONTRAST) << endl;         // Contrast of the image (only for cameras)
    cout << "Image saturation: " << cvGetCaptureProperty(pCapture, CV_CAP_PROP_SATURATION) << endl;     // Saturation of the image (only for cameras)
    cout << "Image hue: " << cvGetCaptureProperty(pCapture, CV_CAP_PROP_HUE) << endl;           // Hue of the image (only for cameras)

    // Create an image from the frame capture
    pFrame = cvQueryFrame(pCapture);

    // Create a greyscale image which is the size of our captured image
    pProcessedFrame = cvCreateImage(cvSize(pFrame->width, pFrame->height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);

    // Create a frame to use as our temporary copy of the current frame but in grayscale mode
    tempFrame = cvCreateImage(cvSize(pFrame->width, pFrame->height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);

    // Loop controling vars
    char keypress;
    bool quit = false;

    while (quit == false)
    {
        // Make an image from the raw capture data
        // Note: cvQueryFrame is a combination of cvGrabFrame and cvRetrieveFrame
        pFrame = cvQueryFrame(pCapture);

        // Draw the original frame in our window
        cvShowImage("WebCam", pFrame);

        // Process the grame to find the edges
        pProcessedFrame = findEdges(pFrame, lowSliderPosition, highSliderPosition, 3);

        // Showed the processed output in our other window
        cvShowImage("Processed WebCam", pProcessedFrame);

        // Wait 20 milliseconds
        keypress = cvWaitKey(20);

        // Set the flag to quit if escape was pressed
        if (keypress == 27)
        {
            quit = true;
        }

    } // End of while loop

    // Release our stream capture object to free up any resources it has been using and release any file/device handles
    cvReleaseCapture(&pCapture);

    // Release our images
    cvReleaseImage(&pFrame);
    cvReleaseImage(&pProcessedFrame);
    // This causes errors if you don't set it to NULL before releasing it. Maybe because we assign
    // it to pProcessedFrame as the end result of the findEdges function, and we've already released pProcessedFrame!!
    tempFrame = NULL;
    cvReleaseImage(&tempFrame);

    // Destory all windows
    cvDestroyAllWindows();
}
```

Comment: Your code fails to test if `pFrame` is NULL.

Comment: And you should **really** use the C++ API, the C API you are using is obsolete and won't be supported in the future. (and you tagged "C++", not "C")

Comment: please rewrite that code using the c++ api.

Comment: obsolete? you say to use another API like CImg?

Answer (score -1):

Thank you all. I found solution, my cam not capturing image, I change to another camera and now the code is running fine.